# How to subscribe to an event with reflection. C#

Tags: c#, events, reflection

I can't seem to figure out why this is throwing "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type." Specifically this part `method.CreateDelegate(eventInfos[0].EventHandlerType, new Commands());`

```
//These are defined at the top of the class
public delegate Task MessageReceivedAsyncDelegate(SocketMessage arg);
public delegate void MessageReceivedDelegate(SocketMessage arg);
public event MessageReceivedAsyncDelegate MessageReceivedCommandAsync;
public event MessageReceivedDelegate MessageReceivedCommand;
//These are defined at the top of the class


    Type B = typeof(Base);
    Type C = typeof(Commands);
    MethodInfo[] methods = C.GetMethods();
    foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
    {
        EventInfo[] eventInfos = B.GetEvents();
        if(method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SubscribeToMessageRecivedAttribute)).Any()
        {
            if (method.ReturnType == typeof(Task))
            {
                try { eventInfos[0].AddEventHandler(C, method.CreateDelegate(eventInfos[0].EventHandlerType, new Commands())); }
                catch(Exception exception) { Console.WriteLine(exception); }
            }
            else eventInfos[1].AddEventHandler(C, method.CreateDelegate(eventInfos[1].EventHandlerType, new Commands()));
        }
    }
```

Method which it's trying to add

```
  public partial class Commands : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [SubscribeToMessageRecived]
        public static async Task Mock(SocketMessage arg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mocking");
            if (Base.mockList.Contains((int)arg.Author.Id))
            {
                char[] msgArray = arg.Content.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < arg.Content.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (DaMef.RandomRange(0,3) == 1) msgArray[i] = msgArray[i].ToString().ToLower().ToCharArray()[0];
                    else msgArray[i] = msgArray[i].ToString().ToUpper().ToCharArray()[0];
                }

            string finalString = msgArray.ToString();
            await arg.Channel.SendMessageAsync(finalString + "\nhttps://imgur.com/a/HsiBmYc");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to subscribe all methods in the Commands with "SubscribeToMessageRecivedAttribute" to an event.

There are answers online but none seem to be it. (Or maybe I just didn't understand them.) I've never used reflections and have barely used events so sorry if it's something stupid.

Comment: What is `eventInfos[0].EventHandlerType`?

Comment: I think it's a way to get the type of that event. (I think.) I've also tried typeOf(MessageReceivedAsyncDelegate) and that didn't change the error.

Comment: Your Mock method isn't an event...

Comment: Am I miss understanding something? I can do MessageReceivedCommandAsync += Commands.Mock; And that works just fine. I'm trying to do the same with reflections.